# How can I know the datetime of a response cached by a service worker through Workbox?

Tags: caching, service-worker, progressive-web-apps, workbox

In my application, it is important for the user to know when the data was updated for the last time.

For example, let's say that the response from a Web API is cached like this:

```
workbox.routing.registerRoute(
  /https:\/\/api\.service\.com\/resource.*/,
  workbox.strategies.cacheFirst({
    cacheName: 'resource',
    plugins: [
      new workbox.expiration.Plugin({
        maxAgeSeconds: ONE_HOUR,
      }),
    ]
  }),
)
```

During one hour, the response will come from cache, and it can be much longer if the user is offline.

How can I know the original response date/time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd probably want to retrieve that information from the `Date:` header of the response. Unfortunately, if you're dealing with a CORS response from a third-party server, the `Date:` header is not available by default—only the [simple response headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Simple_response_header) are available.

So the first thing you'd want to do is make sure that the API you're using sets [`Access-Control-Expose-Headers: Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Expose-Headers) on its HTTP responses.

I don't know how you're reading the API response in your web app, but let's assume that you're using `fetch()` to obtain the response (which may or may not come from the service worker's cache) and then processing the response as JSON. Code to examine the `Date:` header could look something like:

```
const response = await fetch('https://api.service.com/resource');
const dateAsString = response.headers.get('Date');
const dateAsMillis = Date.parse(dateAsString);

// Do something with dateAsMillis, like comparing it to Date.now().
if ((Date.now() - dateAsMillis) < SOME_THRESHOLD) {
  const json = await response.json();
  // Etc.
}
```

Comment: So if I understand well, in general, the "Date" header, and maybe any header, are preserved, not just the response body?

Comment: All response headers that would normally be available at runtime via JavaScript are persisted and recreated when you save/read a response from Cache Storage. The tricky thing is that there are rules as to which headers are available in general; like I mentioned, this is a limited list by default for CORS responses. https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-response-cors-exposed-header-name-list